# Service Worker fails to serve cached resources without at least one reload

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying a simple service worker example modified from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

In `main.js` I have:

```
const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        try {
            const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("./sw.js", {
                scope: "./",
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Registration failed with ${error}`);
        }
    }
};
registerServiceWorker();
```

and in `sw.js` I have

```
const CACHE_NAME = "food-journal-v1";
const ASSETS = [
    "index.html",
    "ReviewDetails.html",
    "CreatePage.html",
    "static/CoveredByYourGrace-Regular.ttf",
    "static/CreatePage.css",
    "static/Form.css",
    "static/homepage.css",
    "static/ReviewDetails.css",
    "assets/images/0-star.svg",
    "assets/images/1-star.svg",
    "assets/images/2-star.svg",
    "assets/images/3-star.svg",
    "assets/images/4-star.svg",
    "assets/images/5-star.svg",
    "assets/images/default_plate.png",
    "assets/images/delete_icon_for_interface.png",
    "assets/images/edit_button_for_interface.png",
    "assets/images/Grouppink.png",
    "assets/images/home_button_for_interface.png",
    "assets/images/favicon.ico",
    "assets/images/Logo.png",
    "assets/scripts/CreatePage.js",
    "assets/scripts/localStorage.js",
    "assets/scripts/main.js",
    "assets/scripts/ReviewCard.js",
    "assets/scripts/ReviewDetails.js",
];

self.addEventListener("install", async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    await cache.addAll(ASSETS);
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
    event.respondWith(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
        return fetch(event.request).then((fetchedResponse) => {
            cache.put(event.request, fetchedResponse.clone());
            return fetchedResponse;
        }).catch(() => {
            return cache.match(event.request);
        });
    }));
});
```

Everything seems to be working fine. When I hard refresh the page and inspect the cache, I see that all specified items in ASSETS is populated into cache:
[image]

However, if I immediately set my browser to offline mode (ie disable cache, restrict bandwidth to offline) and reload the page, I see that several resources are unable to be fetched by the service worker:

[image]

Repeating the same experiment, but this time if I reload the page one extra time just before going offline, the service worker has no issues returning the cached resources. None of the resources on service workers suggests any issue like this should be possible. What might be causing this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I discovered that the promises returned had `PromiseResult = undefined` which led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813582/service-worker-cache-matchrequest-returns-undefined) which seems to have solved the issue. Why VARY header matching is an issue on only the first page load is still unclear.